# importing custom made package from another directory

Tags: python-3.x

I recently developed a package with the following structure:

```
.
├── Foo
│   ├── module1.py
│   ├── module2.py
│   ├── __init__.py
```

where we have:

```
#__init__.py
from module1 import function1, function2
from module2 import function3
```

```
#module1.py
def function1():
   print("Hello")

def function2():
   print("World")
```

```
#module2.py
def function3():
   print("Hello again")
```

I wish to be able to import my full package Foo at once from another directory (with no relative path I can relate to).

For instance, I would like to be able to call `Foo.module1.function1()` in my scripts on another drive.
I cannot use sys.path, and I cannot just move either my script or package into parent/child directories.

I know I can import all modules one by one from a specific directory using importlib (cf. [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)), and then looping, for instance with glob, but I read that configuring the `__init__` file should allow me to import everything at once. Any advice ? (for what it matters, using Python3.9, with no access to PyCharm)